# How to attach ItemID to joomla footermenu

Tags: joomla

I am don't know joomla, but familiar with wordpress & PHP & wants to change some links in my clients existing project.

I have a menu which is a link like http://www.smarti.com.sa/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6&Itemid=107 while calling it from top navigation  menu.

developer has taken same link in footer but it redirects to 
http://www.smarti.com.sa/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6

Now i want `ItemID` in footer link also.

My Site URL is http://www.smarti.com.sa/

In that please Products > Microsoft.

Please give solution

Comment: How has the link been added to the footer? If it is a hard coded link then just edit the file and add the Itemid.

Answer (score 0):

As per your post, Your menu link for now is : http://www.smarti.com.sa/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6 .

But, you want to use this like : http://www.smarti.com.sa/index.php/your_menu_name.

You can use aliases of menu links.
You can find aliases here, When you create/edit a menu link from backend of joomla you can see an alias associated with it. You can also find Aliases of menu link from grid screen of you menu type.

For showing Menu in front end you have to create CUSTOM HTML module, You can find how to create Custom HTML module here : http://vinaora.com/2012/09/how-to-add-custom-html-to-your-joomla-site-2/

Now, How can you find HTML to write in thst Custom HTML Module? So, for this you can go the page of front-end where that menu is visible. Now prss CTRL+U, you will see the HTML of that page. Here, you have to find the HTML of those menus.

In this HTML, you will find the links like : index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=6

Now, you have to replace these links with index.php/alias_of_your_menu.

Now paste the edited HTML in Custom HTML module and save it by selecting a proper Position.

Comment: i want to add `ItemID` in my footer link. both footer & top menu coming from `main_menu` created ion back-end. in top menu link comes proper(perfect), but in footer `ItemID` does not come. why like this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use joomla menu module in the footer.

Joomla also has the option to display second level menu items in a menu module.

To do this:

```
Set the Start Level to "1" and the End Level to "1".
```

That's all. Good Luck.

Comment: I have set like that, but still `ItemID` does not shows in link

Comment: Are you using joomla menu module or custom HTML? When am inspecting the code it seems like you are using custom HTML module. Use joomla menu module, then everything will work perfect.